# Magento Observer to copy customer comment to Order Comments / Firecheckout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Having some trouble with this one. We have a client that needs to add the customer comment field from Firecheckout into the Order Comments that appears on the backend for administers when viewing orders. I have created an observer, and have tried several different methods but no success.

Here is my code:

etc/modules/decoder_ordercomments.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<decoder_ordercomments>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </decoder_ordercomments>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Here is app/code/local/decoder/model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class decoder_ordercomments_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
 /**
 * Add a customer order comment when the order is placed
 * @param object $event
 * @return
 */
public function saveOrder($evt)
{
  $_order   = $evt->getOrder();
  $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

  $_comments = strip_tags($_order.getData('firecheckout_customer_comment'));

  if(!empty($_comments)){
    $_comments = 'Additional Order Comments: ' . $_comments;
    $_order->addStatusHistoryComment($_comments);
    $_order->save();
  }

  return $this;
 }
}
```

Here is app/code/local/decoder/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <decoder_ordercomments>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
    </decoder_ordercomments>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
  <events>
     <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
       <observers>
         <decoder_ordercomments>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>decoder_ordercomments_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>saveOrder</method>
         </decoder_ordercomments>
        </observers>
      </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
   </events>
  </frontend>
```

I thought about hacking the firecheckout code itself, but I would very much prefer to keep this as a standalone observer to avoid having to update this every time TM updates it.